# Showing On Sale Products from different Categories

Tags: category

Im rather new with magento and also PHP so be gently :) I have got this code that goes through all of my products and displays the ones with Special prices (on sale). I have this in a block at the moment so i can put it at the top of my product landing pages so the customer can see the on sale products without having to look through the whole category.

However the code at the moment is going through ALL of my categories and displaying ALL products, how would i go about changing it so it only goes through the products in the category the user is looking at??

```
<?php
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/advanced_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addStoreFilter();

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($_productCollection);


$todayDate = date('m/d/y');
$tomorrow = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('y'));
$tomorrowDate = date('m/d/y', $tomorrow);

$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
    0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $tomorrowDate),
    1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
    ), 'left');

?>

<div class="listing-type-grid catalog-listing">
<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
<?php $i=0; foreach($_productCollection as $_product):?>
<?php if($i++%3==0): ?>
<ol class="grid-row">
 <?php endif; ?>
<li class="item">


<p class="product-image">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135, 135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image')) ?>" />
                    </a>
                </p>
                <h5><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?></a></h5>
                <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <button type="button" class="form-button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
                <?php else: ?>
                <div class="out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                 </li>

        <?php if($i%3==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
        </ol>
        <?php endif; ?>







 <?php endforeach ?>
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

```
                                   ***ANSWERED!!***
```

Someone on the magento forum has answered this for me so i thought i would share in case anyone else ever wants to know how to do this.

All you need to do is add these two lines

```
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
            $currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();


->addCategoryFilter($_category)
```

So it becomes

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
            $currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();

$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/advanced_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
           ->addCategoryFilter($_category)
            ->addStoreFilter();
```

This answer came from elfling in the magento community, i cant take the credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on the magento forum has answered this for me so i thought i would share in case anyone else ever wants to know how to do this.

All you need to do is add these two lines

```
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
            $currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();


->addCategoryFilter($_category)
So it becomes

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
            $currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();

$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/advanced_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
           ->addCategoryFilter($_category)
            ->addStoreFilter();
```

This answer came from elfling in the magento community, i cant take the credit.